# Keep dragged objects flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frames

I have a flash project with only one layer and two key frames,
in the first frame i have some object i enabled the drag over them; and a button to go to and stop to the other key frame, the issue is when i drag my objects over the first frame then go to the other frame and get back again with another button with go to and stop method all my dragged objects returns to their original places, how i could keep them as they were dragged.

I tried to change go to and stop to the previous frame by using:
MovieClip(this.root).prevScene()gotoAndStop(1);
and no use, 
you kind help please.

Comment: Don't use two frames, period.

Comment: Thanks Vesper, but then what to do to change from view to view?

Comment: You can use two or more containers, one per "view". Once you are about to change views, you hide/remove the present container and unhide/add the desired container. These in turn contain all the visuals for the selected screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use two layers.  Put anything you want to persist between the two frames on one layer without any keyframes.  Put anything you want to remove/add onto the layer with 2 keyframes.
If you want them to temporarily disappear you can call movieclip.visible=false; when you go to the next frame, then movieclip.visible=true when you go back to the first frame.  You can either call this on each movieclip, or add them all to a container movieclip and call container_mc.visible=true/false;